# Python Read Line Regex Action

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to build a script in Python that will read a line of text in a file, search for a list item built from a re.compile and if it's finds one to enter the data on an excel spreadsheet. Everything seems to be working up to the point it needs to match the list items to the text files line to determine it should write to the excel file - Here's a snippet of the code:

```
filename = open(logfile, "r")
for text in filename.readlines():
    text = text.rstrip()
    regexip = re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})', text)
if regexip is not None and regexip not in iplist:
iplist.append(regexip)
print iplist
portlist = []
for text in filename.readlines():
    text = text.rstrip()
    regexport = re.findall('\d+/\w+', text)
    if regexport is not None and regexport not in portlist:
        portlist.append(regexport)
print portlist
for line in filename.readlines():
    if regexip in line:
        sheet.write(row,ipcol,ip)
        row += 1
    else:
        filename.close()
```

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html ... better title, what did you do, what you expected to happen, what did happen.

Comment: I think the title is pretty accurate and I included all of the items you mentioned... It's a python script that's reading a line against a regular expression to perform an action on a match. I've included my code and explained it does everything it's supposed to do except write the item captured by the regex to the excel file. 

If I had to guess the problem is in the last enumeration but honestly I'm pretty new at this and I'm sure there's a much better way to do the whole thing.

Comment: You have two regular expressions, but you don't say which one doesn't work. You didn't add the text, so there's no way to know why it doesn't match the regex. Most of the code you included is irrelevant. You didn't include the results you get now (content of `regexip` and `regexport`). Please provide those at least if you expect to get any help.

Comment: Here's the text and xls format - Providing a link since I can't paste it:
http://www.honortech.net/test.txt
http://www.honortech.net/test.xls

Comment: What I'd like to see happen is if the line contains an IP address to write it in column B then row +1. If the line contains a port # to write it in column C then row +1. I'm trying to achieve a logical grouping of ports identified under each IP address.
http://www.honortech.net/script.rtf
Here is a link to the full script after I've made some tweaks.

Comment: I solved the issue - Thank you